# Automatically sync changes on master codebase to forked codebase in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I have 2 projects in my gitlab account named zip/production (master) and map/production (forked from master). Whenever i make changes to zip/production the same should be automatically updated to map/production but should keep the additional files which are there in map/production as it is. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at git hooks. When you push a change to zip/production, have the pre-push hook kick in and push to your other forked repo too.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the additional code present in map/production as it is while using this ?

Comment: Sort of. If you push new stuff, your local additional changes may need to be merged.

Comment: You might want to think about using more than one branch, and manually merging up your fork's code to its feature branch.

Answer (score 0):

Not only possible, but also pretty easy!

```
# .git/hooks/post-receive on the remote:


#!/usr/bin/bash

IFS=' '
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do

  echo "$remote_ref" | egrep '^refs\/heads\/[A-Z]+-[0-9]+$' >/dev/null && {
    ref=`echo $remote_ref | sed -e 's/^refs\/heads\///'`
    echo Forwarding feature branch to features-only repository: $ref
    git push -q features-only $ref  --force
  }

done
```

This example takes only a subset of branches (in the Jira issue format, XYZ-1234) and forwards them to a second repository. You can leave the conditional away of course to forward everything.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the additional code in map/production as it is on the map/production instance ?

Comment: @sunshine, what do you mean?

Comment: i have modified the code on map/production instance i.e the forked instance and i want to keep all the files that have been added as it is. these additional files are not in zip/production i.e the master and its perfect. Now i have also made changes on master and i want to merge them into the forked instance without affecting additional files on forked instance..

Comment: sometimes there will be merge conflicts, it's not possible to automatically keep both sides of a merge conflict.